# Conectar sistema Java ao banco de dados no servidor

Tags: java, mysql, sql, permissões

Tenho um sistema Desk no qual estou tentando conectar a uma base de dados que fica no servidor. Porém toda vez que tento conectar da o seguinte erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host
>   'nco-inf-04.cop.com.br' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL
>   server"

Como libero permissão pra todos os usuários que irão ter o sistema instalado?

Classe Conexão:

```
public class Conexao {

    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://10.70.111.24:3306/db_prestadores";
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Conectar ao banco
    public static Connection abrir() throws Exception {
        // Registrar o driver
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        // Capturar a conexão
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
        // Retorna a conexao aberta
        return conn;

    }

}
```

WorkBench:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tendo esse banco localizado em um servidor, já me aconteceu uma vez, alguma regra de firewall ou de conexão não permitir minha entrada. De uma olhada nas suas regras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando um novo usuário:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]